# compare 2 csv files in shell using awk

Tags: shell, csv, awk

Thanks.

I have 2 csv files which I need to compare them and report back if it's different. file format is same in both files and even first column data (column A) in both files have same content(it's header info).

Tried using awk command but have there is conditions which am not sure how to implement.

conditions :

a. Need to exclude first 2 rows (since those are not required for comparison). can this be achieved by doing :

```
NFR=NR > 2
```

b. If any of the value differ then in output need to report back with header info and it's respective servername along with values.

File1.csv :

```
Status Check
APP servers
Server name,abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,
Summary,,,,,,
System Start Time,Nov/12/2016 20:12:24 GMT,Nov/12/2016 20:15:38 GMT,Nov/12/2016 20:15:37 GMT,Nov/12/2016 20:15:57 GMT,Nov/12/2016 20:11:42 GMT,
System Life Time,118day.14hr.15min.19sec,118day.14hr.12min.01sec,118day.14hr.12min.03sec,118day.14hr.11min.44sec,118day.14hr.16min.01sec,
OS Version,SunOS 5.10,SunOS 5.10,SunOS 5.10,SunOS 5.10,SunOS 5.10,
Service Pack Version,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,
State,Up,Up,Up,Up,Up,
```

File2.csv :

```
Status Check
APP servers
Server name,abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,
Summary,,,,,,
System Start Time,Nov/13/2016 20:12:24 GMT,Nov/13/2016 20:15:38 GMT,Nov/13/2016 20:15:37 GMT,Nov/13/2016 20:15:57 GMT,Nov/13/2016 20:11:42 GMT,
System Life Time,118day.14hr.15min.19sec,118day.14hr.12min.01sec,118day.14hr.12min.03sec,118day.14hr.11min.44sec,118day.14hr.16min.01sec,
OS Version,SunOS 5.10,SunOS 5.10,SunOS 5.11,SunOS 5.12,SunOS 5.10,
Service Pack Version,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,Generic_147148-26,
State,Down,Up,Down,Up,Down,
```

Result/Output:

```
OS Version value is different for server name ghi and jkl : 5.11,5.12
State value is different for server name abc, ghi and mno : Down,Down,Down
```

Is it possible to exclude 5/6 column for comparison as well since that will be date/time related so not required for comparison.

can just give key value(say column b/c) only those specific columns data gets compared b/w files ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question is "Yes, it is possible". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Comment: sure ghoti. got your point. I forgot to add my code inital post. point noted going forward will include.thanks,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may give you an idea how to approach the problem

```
$ paste -d, file{1,2} | 
  awk -F,     'NR<3  {next}
               NR==3 {n=split($0,h); m=n/2} 
      NR!=5 && NR!=6 {for(i=2;i<=m-1;i++) 
                        if($i!=$(i+m)) print $1,h[i],$i,$(i+m)}'


OS Version ghi SunOS 5.10 SunOS 5.11
OS Version jkl SunOS 5.10 SunOS 5.12
State abc Up Down
State ghi Up Down
State mno Up Down
```

your output formatting can be added but will complicate the code. Since your values contain space you may want to keep comma as output field separator as well.

Comment: thanks @karakfa. I tried to run the your code but getting file not found error. i replaced $paste -d, actual file1 name, actual file2 name | awk -F....am i missing something here

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add open/close curly barckets

Comment: how can I add the comma as output field separtor

Comment: use `awk -F, -v OFS=,` instead

Comment: Thank you. OFS=, does the work. one last thing, how can I skip start time and life time for comparision since time value will always be different so no need to compare them.

Comment: thanks, got it. now am trying to get the result in tabular format, so far I was able to get something but not able to get tab space b/w the values.

Comment: awk -F, -v OFS=, 'BEGIN {
        print "|========================================|"
        print "|        Comparsion Report               |"
        print "|========================================|"
        print "|ColumnName, IP Address, Before, After   |"
        print "|========================================|"
 } NR==3 {n=split($0,h); m=n/2} NR>6  {for(i=2;i<=m-1;i++) if($i!=$(i+m)) print $1,h[i],$i,$(i+m)}'
        printf "|=======================================|\n";
}

Comment: ok, got it. used -v OFS=,'\t' to get tab space value between the values in the output.